# how to reset shiny actionButton in R?

Tags: r, action-button

I want to execute the if statement only once when the `actionButton` is pressed once. So, I want to reset the `actionButton` because the if statement is executed continuously. T.T

Here is my code.

```
      output$action_btn <- renderUI({
        actionButton("act_btn", class="btn-primary", "active")
      })

      output$test <- renderPlot({
        if(input$act_btn!= 0){
         (execution code..)
        }
      })

      input$act_btn <- 0  #This is Error.
```

When I press the actionButton, It works well.

The problem is `input$act_btn <- 0`. I want to reset the value of act_btn.

Is there a method to solve this problem?

Comment: https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/167 helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I'll try it!

Answer (score 3):

A little late, but I just went through this process recently and found [this blog post from Antoine Guillot](http://enhancedatascience.com/2017/03/01/three-r-shiny-tricks-to-make-your-shiny-app-shines-33-buttons-to-delete-edit-and-compare-datatable-rows/) very helpful.

In essence he creates a proxy variable in the JS client side, that always gets updated on button click. Then in your r code, you observe the proxy variable and can continue the logic as if you had reset the button status to 0.

```
tags$script("$(document).on('click', '#Main_table button', function () {
 Shiny.onInputChange('lastClickId',this.id);
 Shiny.onInputChange('lastClick', Math.random())
});")
```

In this code, any click event in the shiny output `#Main_table` containing a `button` will trigger the `onClick` event. Then using shiny js commands, a new `input` variable is created which now contains the id of the button clicked.

You will notice

```
Shiny.onInputChange('lastClick', Math.random())
```

This is the "proxy" that you use to `observeEvent` on, and take action with.

Section f. here http://enhancedatascience.com/2017/03/01/three-r-shiny-tricks-to-make-your-shiny-app-shines-33-buttons-to-delete-edit-and-compare-datatable-rows/

Hope it helps someone else as much as it did me.